# p5.js How to stop rotation of certain elements

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am drawing some rotating rectangles in p5.js, and it is all working fine. Then I need some text to be displayed on top of rectangles and I want it to be motionless. However, the text is spinning as well. I have tried some solutions like setting rotate(0) or value negative to the rotation of last drawn rectangle, but nothing works.

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(size, colorR, colorG, colorB, angle) {
        this.size = size;
        this.colorR = colorR;
        this.colorG = colorG;
        this.colorB = colorB;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.actualAngle = this.angle;
    }

    draw() {
        stroke(0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        fill(this.colorR, this.colorG, this.colorB);
        rotate(this.actualAngle);
        rect(0, 0, this.size, this.size);
    }

    increaseAngle() {
        this.actualAngle += this.angle;
    }

    getActualAngle(){
        return this.actualAngle;
    }
}

var rectangles = [];

 function setup() {
    var canvas1 = createCanvas(800, 700);
    canvas1.parent("regLog");
    var size = 12;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let ranR = random(150);
        let ranG = random(150);
        let ranB = random(150);
        let angle = random(-0.005, 0.005);
        rectangles.push(new Rectangle(size, ranR, ranG, ranB, angle));
        size += 50;
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(255);

    rectMode(CENTER);
    translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    for (var i = rectangles.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        rectangles[i].draw();
    }

    if (second() % 1 == 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
            rectangles[i].increaseAngle();
        }
    }

    rotate(0);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 255, 255, 0);    
    rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    textSize(60);
    text("Coming soon!", 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used push() to "save" the current rotation settings and then pop() to restore them after each time you draw a rectangle. When you use rotate(), it rotates the all of the future shapes you draw, so the changes are "permanent" unless you're very careful to reset.

You can see it work in this jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/ozsLtxhb/237/

i commented out the part where you assign a parent just for the jsfiddle to work so uncomment it before you copy-paste it into anything

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(size, colorR, colorG, colorB, angle) {
        this.size = size;
        this.colorR = colorR;
        this.colorG = colorG;
        this.colorB = colorB;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.actualAngle = this.angle;
    }

    draw() {
        /*push here*/
        push();
        stroke(0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        fill(this.colorR, this.colorG, this.colorB);
        rotate(this.actualAngle);
        rect(0, 0, this.size, this.size);
        /*pop here*/
        pop();
    }

    increaseAngle() {
        this.actualAngle += this.angle;
    }

    getActualAngle(){
        return this.actualAngle;
    }
}

var rectangles = [];

 function setup() {
    var canvas1 = createCanvas(800, 700);
/*     canvas1.parent("regLog"); */
    var size = 12;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let ranR = random(150);
        let ranG = random(150);
        let ranB = random(150);
        let angle = random(-0.005, 0.005);
        rectangles.push(new Rectangle(size, ranR, ranG, ranB, angle));
        size += 50;
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(255);

    rectMode(CENTER);
    translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    for (var i = rectangles.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        rectangles[i].draw();
    }

    if (second() % 1 == 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
            rectangles[i].increaseAngle();
        }
    }

    rotate(0);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 255, 255, 0);    
    rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    textSize(60);
    text("Coming soon!", 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Isn't it a bit strange that the function rotates whole canvas instead of elements being drawn? Is it how it's supposed to be or it's some kind of bug?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I was really unclear, but it doesn’t rotate the canvas so much as change how the shapes are displayed from that point on. But since the changes “”stack”” if you call rotate more than once (rotate 10 + rotate 20 = rotate 30) i usually just think about it as the canvas being rotated because it’s like turning a sheet of paper. To be clear, it doesn’t rotate the canvas, that was just a mistake in wording on my part!! Sorry, that’s my bad, I’m really glad you caught it.

Comment: No problem! Also, I was thinking about your question yesterday, and realized that your problem is that calling rotate(0) doesn’t set the current rotation to 0, it just adds 0 to the current rotation. So if you had rotate(70) and did rotate(0) it’s still rotate(70).

Comment: If what you said is true, rotate(-70) should make rotate 0, right? I am curious because I have tried that and it didn't work. I did something like this with rotate function for the text: rotate(-(rectangles[rectangles.length-1]));

Comment: Why only subtract the rotation of the last rectangle though? It looks like every time you draw one of your rectangles rotate is called. so after your forloop you’d have to account for and subtract every single one of those rotations because they stack on top of each other.

Comment: so if you want to do it the subtraction way, this also works -> https://jsfiddle.net/ozsLtxhb/267/

Comment: You are right, I forgot to subtract the rest of them. I just can't remember that it adds all the values of rotate. My bad ;)